# Tensorflow - How to ignore certain labels

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a fully convolutional network and train it on the Pascal VOC dataset, however after reading up on the labels in the set, I see that I need to somehow ignore the "void" label. In Caffe their softmax function has an argument to ignore labels, so I'm wondering what the mechanic is, so I can implement something similar in tensorflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tensorflow you're feeding the data in `feed_dict` right? Generally you'd want to just pre-process the data and remove the unwanted samples - don't give them to tensorflow for processing.

My prefered approach is a producer-consumer model where you fire up a tensorflow queue and load it with samples from a loader thread which just skips `enqueuing` your *void* samples.

In training your model `dequeue` samples in the model (you don't use `feed_dict` in the optimize step). This way you're not bothering to write out a whole new dataset with the specific preprocessing step you're interested in today (tomorrow you're likely to find you want to do some other preprocessing step).

As a side comment, I think tensorflow is a little more do-it-yourself than some other frameworks. But I tend to like that, it abstracts enough to be convenient, but not so much that you don't understand what's happening. When you implement it you understand it, that's the motto that comes to mind with tensorflow.

Comment: I'll add a side comment that there are tricks to masking the gradient for certain samples in cases where you have multiple loss functions. I don't think that applies in this case so I leave it only as a side note. If it's relevant to your question I can elaborate.

Comment: Right, so I was thinking as a last resort to just preprocess the void labels out, but seeing that Caffe handles it internally I was hoping someone knew how exactly that process is handled so I could implement it and not need to preprocess.

Comment: Technically you could mask the gradient by multiplying your loss by a 0 or 1 value depending on whether you want to a gradient to propagate on that example or not, but that's wildly overkill for this use case. There is no built-in functionality to mask samples in the standard loss functions. There are such things for recurrent neural networks where masking time steps is par for the course, but again, outside the realm of your question. I suspect Tensorflow is a little more "raw" in this respect, but let it grow on you, that might not turn out to be all bad in the long run.